# How can i read gaming steering wheel input in delphi?

Tags: delphi

I have a steering wheel connected to my computer...
My problem is that i want to get the state of the accelerator how much % is pressed...can i do this in delphi? how can i communicate with the device ? do you know any tutorials ?

Comment: Have you tried monitoring the messages one of your apps receives?

Comment: What model of steering wheel?

Comment: I'd recommend asking this on the games development-specific Stack Exchange site: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ as you're more likely to reach an audience who will know. (Moved from an Answer to a Comment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a HID then perhaps this lib is useful [Human Interface Device controller suite](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=14&Itemid=33)

Answer (score 2):

If your steering wheel is connected via USB, it probably interfaces with your system using the standard USB Hid device class.

For help with delphi and USB Hid device class, look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017917/how-to-read-hid-device-data-by-using-tjvhiddevice).

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with steering wheels, but I suppose the acceleration value is just an axis value of one of the possible six axes of a standard joystick. If so, then you can do with any joystick component which supports multiple axes (maybe Jedi's TJvJoystick, no experience with). Or try [this simple one](https://github.com/NLDelphi/NLDJoystick), set the `Advanced` property to `True` and add the following handler to the `OnMove` event to find out which axis is the acceleration pedal:

```
procedure TForm1.NLDJoystick1Move(Sender: TNLDJoystick;
  const JoyPos: TJoyRelPos; const Buttons: TJoyButtons);
begin
  LabelX.Caption := FloatToStr(JoyPos.X);
  LabelY.Caption := FloatToStr(JoyPos.Y);
  LabelZ.Caption := FloatToStr(JoyPos.Z);
  LabelR.Caption := FloatToStr(JoyPos.R);
  LabelU.Caption := FloatToStr(JoyPos.U);
  LabelV.Caption := FloatToStr(JoyPos.V);
end;
```

Comment: F1026 File not found: 'NLDJoystick.dcu'?

Comment: @wittrup You have to compile the source/package to create the dcu's.

Comment: I know.  Thanks.  I figured it out in the end.  Dunno what I did wrong first but...well.. yeah...